# Inverse Matrix Implications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A and B are two square matrices that are invertible,

I know its false that A+B must also invertible.

However Im not sure that: if A and B are invertible, then A + B is invertible, or A-B is invertible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim $A,B$ invertible $\implies$ $A-B$ or $A+B$ is invertible is false. Consider
 $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\\ 
B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$ Then
$$
A+B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\\
A-B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Neither of these is invertible.

Comment: thanks thats it

Comment: Could you accept my answer?